# Joomla k2 items additional meta tags

Tags: plugins, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

I use joomla with k2 and i need to add Opeh Graph meta tags to my items. I alreday have meta description and others which i don't need. I need to add meta `og:image` ,`og:image:height` and `og:image:width`. I try to do this with JS, but than facebook grabber doesn't see my meta tags. So i need to add them with backend part. Also i need the oportunity to change thir values from my admin panel. Maybe you know some plugins(free) or something else?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more info as to why you are trying to use the width and height meta? This may help us give better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free plugin and component by ITPrism http://itprism.com. You can find it here http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/itpmeta.
The site where you can directly download is http://itprism.com/free-joomla-extensions/others/open-graph-meta

**NOTE:**  You have to install the ITPrism library too. So you need to install two packages. The downloads can be found at the bottom of these pages

1. Main component Download

http://itprism.com/free-joomla-extensions/others/open-graph-meta

2. ITPrism Library

http://itprism.com/free-joomla-extensions/others/software-development-kit

Download the latest version 1.14.

This will work perfectly and solve your issue. No need of JS.

Comment: Thank you!
It works great. But if we have many posts it is very uncomfrotable to the client make tags for every post through the url. Maybe you know some another solutions where we can add meta to the page of post settings?

Answer (score 0):

K2 has OpenGraph properties out-of-the-box. I've confirmed on a K2 site I have built that the `og:image` tag is there for K2 items and categories. However, I have never seen any use of the `og:image:height` and `og:image:width` tags. These are valid [Structured Properties](http://ogp.me/#structured), but they are optional and rarely get used. Thus, you will likely have to override K2 to output those values.

For the rest of your pages, you can try the [Phoca Open Graph Plugin](http://www.phoca.cz/phoca-open-graph-plugin). I have used that with good success, as well.